# Do I still need to map my USB Ports after installing MacOS Monterey with OpenCore Legacy Patcher on an unsupported Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, usb, monterey, mapping, open-source

I am using a Macbook Pro 11,3 2014. I have installed opencore with MacOS Montery using the [OpenCore Legacy Patcher 1.2.1](https://github.com/dortania/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher) on my unsupported Mac. I did this by flashing Monterey to a USB stick with [OpenCore legacy patcher](https://github.com/dortania/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher), and installed MacOS from USB. Afterwords, I used the "Post-Install Root Patch" button on [OpenCore Legacy Patcher](https://github.com/dortania/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher) on my Mac.

My question is, after all of this, do I still need to map my USB Ports using [USBMap](https://github.com/corpnewt/USBMap), or does OpenCore Legacy Patcher automatically take care of this for you? Any help is much appreciated!